# "Group of Units" functor is co-representable

Tags: category-theory

Consider the functor $Rings\rightarrow Groups$ which sends a ring $R$ to its group of units $R^\times$. I am trying to show that this functor is co-representable, i.e. naturally isomorphic to $Hom(R,.)$ for some ring $R$. To do this, I tried to set up a correspondence between $Hom(R, A)$ and $A^\times$ for an arbitrary $A$ and some ring $R$, but I cannot seem to find a ring $R$ for which such a correspondence exists. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take $R=\mathbb Z[t,t^{-1}]{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: The goal here is to find the free ring on a unit, so one starts with the free ring on an element and then forces that element to become a unit.